# Number of cards until first pike plus number of tiles- conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Okay, imagine that we draw randomly one card from 52 (hearts, tiles, clovers, pikes). We note the card and then we put it back and then again draw one card until we have pike. So the distribution of $Y$- number of cards until the first pike is geometric i.e.
$P(Y=k)=\Big(\frac{3}{4}\Big)^{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$ , $k=1,2,\dots$.
But now, let $X$- number of tiles until the first pike and we have to compute $E(Y|X=4)$. Is there any easy way?
My idea was:
Let compute conditional distribution $Y|X=4$, then (if there is no mistake)
$P(Y=k|X=4)={k-1\choose 4}\Big(\frac{1}{26}\Big)^{k-5}\cdot\Big(\frac{1}{13}\Big)^{5}$, $k=5,6,\dots$.

This distribution is very hard to compute anything! Even showing that sum of that probabilities is $1$ is very difficult.

Comment: Use symmetry.  There's no difference between hearts, tiles, and clovers in this context, so they must all have the same expectation.

Comment: Honestly it doesn't help me in any way. Simply, how to compute $E(Y|X=4)$?

Comment: I deleted a comment because it contained an error.  My initial comment was intended for the opposite situation, that is$E(X\,|\,Y=4)$.  I'm thinking about how to use the same principle for the actual question

Comment: The trick here is to first work out $E(Y\,|\,X=0)$.  That's the same as the expected number of times you can draw either hearts or clovers before you draw anything else (this point is not obvious, but it is the key.)  Once you have this value then you need to repeat it with the additional constraint that the first four times the "anything else" is a tile  and the fifth time it is a pike.  That part is easy.

Comment: I do not understand it at all.

Comment: So, I claim that $E(Y\,|\,X=0)$ is a geometric process. All you are asking is the expected number of times you can draw $H$ or $C$ before you get either $T$ or $P$ (counting the final draw).  The answer to that is $2$, since it is effectively a fair coin toss.  [Here](http://www.yichijin.com/files/elchanan.pdf) is a link that describes the computation in great detail for a very similar expectation.